# iOS change layer of the view a CATransform3D, subviews of the view was added to the window, resulting in sub-view can not respond to events

Tags: ios

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
view3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.view addSubview:view];
[view addSubview:view2];
[view2 addSubview:view3];
[view3 addSubview:btn];

self.header = view;
[btn addTarget:self  action:@selector(texta) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self updateTransform];
}
-(void)texta
{
   NSLog(@"3333");
}
-(void)updateTransform
{
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 0, 0);
   transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.1, 1.1, 0);
    self.header.layer.transform = transform;
}
```

example for the image, the button move to window-------，and not work when click it.why  change  layer of the view  a CATransform3D, subviews of the view was added to the window, resulting in sub-view can not respond to events?

Comment: transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.1, 1.1, 0);

Comment: where, CATransform3DScale(transform, 1.1, 1.1, 1);